# A Robin Hood based story

Tags: story-identification, books, robin-hood

I recall a children's story i enjoyed.  I can give scraps of memory - can anyone help identify?

There were figurines of Robin Hood and Sherwood Forest.
The kids would enter that world in their sleep.
Their bed would appear as a plateau in that world.
What happened to the figurines in daytime affected the alternate world: on one occasion the figurines were used to demonstrate baseball plays and the next night in Sherwood Forest universe, the big thing was baseball.
There were two house-type dolls who were insanely furious about being neglected.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I know exactly what story you're talking about; I can't remember the title or author, either. Some additional details I recall; if you confirm them, add them to the question: (1) The children's father was ill, hospitalized, and they were visiting an aunt/grandparent who lived near the hospital. (2) At some point, the children recognized that their adventures were tied to the figurines in some way - and that declaring the true nature of the figurines at the people in the dream moved them back to reality.

Comment: Just got back and thank you very much but I didnt remember much of the plot, the imaginings though are still memorable.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I did some intense googling, and it's almost certain that we were both thinking of [*Knight’s Castle* by Edward Eager (Text available at Gutenberg Canada)](https://gutenberg.ca/ebooks/eagere-knightscastle/eagere-knightscastle-00-h.html). From the [synopsis at GoodReads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/312081.Knight_s_Castle):

> When the ancient toy soldier comes alive, the Old One grants Roger's wish to adventure in "yeomanly" Sherwood Forest. Will Roger earn his second wish, to save his father? Need for an operation brings Roger 11 and younger Ann to stay with bossy cousin Eliza and Jack. Can the children convince Ivanhoe to marry Rebecca over Rowena, and conquer the castle - in pjs?

Comment: Thank you as well, totally helpful!!

Comment: If this is, in fact, the story, you can mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of it. This lets everyone know that the answer has been found, and tosses me a bit of rep. If it's not the answer, please edit the question with additional information to indicate what's different about rhe story you remember and this one.